Solution of a PDE for equal arguments
Let's say I have a PDE for a two-variable function $f(x,y)$. If I am interested only in the values of $f$ along the line $y=x$, i.e. in $f(x,x)$, I would try to first solve the PDE and then restrict the solution $f(x,y)$ by setting $y = x$. Now, since the PDE is hard to solve, I wonder whether it would be possible to just set $y = x$ in the PDE itself and only then solve the resulting (ordinary) differential equation.
I guess that this procedure generally gives the wrong solution $f(x,x)$. So, unless it is always prohibited, under which conditions is it possible to take this shortcut?

Not what you are asking, but depending on the specific form of the equation it may help to define say $g(x-y,x+y)=f(x,y)$. Then you can look for example for solutions that are independent of $x+y$.

How exactly are you planning on setting $y=x$ in the PDE itself and get an ODE? You can't replace all $\partial/\partial y$ with $\partial/\partial x$, if that's what you had in mind.

The question originates from the fact that in my context $x$ and $y$ are actually the same variable replicated twice. So, I was overlooking the fact that $x$ and $y$ have to be treated completely independently and indeed I imagined to replace $\partial_y$ with $\partial_x$ (of course very wrong, thanks @HansLundmark!). The question was most probably ill-posed then. However, I think I could try to follow the comment of @John B (thank you!) and check if the PDE rewritten in the variables $z_{\pm} = x \pm y$ exhibits only derivatives w.r.t. $z_{-}$.
